# TcpClient.Connected returns true yet client is not connected, what can I use instead?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sockets

In VB.net I'm using the TcpClient to retrieve a string of data.  I'm constantly checking the .Connected property to verify if the client is connected but even if the client disconnects this still returns true.  What can I use as a workaround for this?

This is a stripped down version of my current code:

```
Dim client as TcpClient = Nothing
client = listener.AcceptTcpClient
do while client.connected = true
   dim stream as networkStream = client.GetStream()
   dim bytes(1024) as byte
   dim numCharRead as integer = stream.Read(bytes,0,bytes.length)
   dim strRead as string = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,i)
loop
```

I would have figured at least the GetStream() call would throw an exception if the client was disconnected but I've closed the other app and it still doesn't...

Thanks.

**EDIT** 
Polling the Client.Available was suggested but that doesn't solve the issue.  If the client is not 'acutally' connected available just returns 0.

The key is that I'm trying to allow the connection to stay open and allow me to receive data multiple times over the same socket connection.

Comment: The `Connected` property only means that you *did* connect some time in the past. It doesn't indicate the current state of the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When NetworkStream.Read returns 0, then the connection has been closed. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(VS.71).aspx):

> If no data is available for reading, the NetworkStream.Read method will block until data is available. To avoid blocking, you can use the DataAvailable property to determine if data is queued in the incoming network buffer for reading. If DataAvailable returns true, the Read operation will complete immediately. The Read operation will read as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter. **If the remote host shuts down the connection, and all available data has been received, the Read method will complete immediately and return zero bytes.**

Answer (score 1):

Better answer:

```
if (client.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
{
    byte[] checkConn = new byte[1];

    if (client.Client.Receive(checkConn, SocketFlags.Peek) == 0)
        throw new IOException();
}
```

Comment: This is really old, but you should comment your code or give explanations because I don't know what your answer is doing at all.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of polling client.connected, maybe use of the NetworkStream's properties to see if there's no more data available?

Anyhow, there's an [ONDotnet.com](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/07/07/netstreams.html) article with TONS of info on listeners and whatnot. Should help you get past your issue...

Comment: The OP wants to know how to detect a disconnect. "Data available" is not the same as "connected".

Answer (score -2):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb0X2.png

LINK=https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.poll?view=netframework-4.0

You need to set up a timer that sends a msg to the other socket from time to time.

Dim TC As New TimerCallback(AddressOf Ping)

Tick = New Threading.Timer(TC, Nothing, 0, 30000)

```
Sub Ping()
    Send("Stil here?")
End Sub
```